Ray separation in waveplates
In a birefringent medium, the ordinary and extraordinary rays have different Pointing-vector directions and, therefore, different propagation directions, since the direction of the Poyting-vector coincides with the direction of the group velocity of the wave.
My question is: since the principle of a waveplate is based on a birefrigent material, in experiments, how one deals with the fact that the ray is broken up in two different directions? In this way, for example, it is not possible for a horizontally polarized light to be converted into a circularly polarized light without the beams of different polarization directions being separated.
Or is the beam separation so small in experiments, that it is almost irrelevant?


Quarter and half wave plates are arranged in such a way, that the axis of the uniaxial birefringent crystal is perpendicular to the direction of travel of light, and parallel to the surface of the plates. In this case the extraordinary ray is not refracted away from the ordinary ray.
Of course, this is not entirely the truth because your beam of light can't be perfectly collimated and you can't adjust the positions of the wave plates sufficiently precisely to guarantee perfectly perpendicular incidence of your beam – but those minor effects can usually be neglected (or compensated, e.g. the shift between the components will primarily relevant away from the center of the beam, as long as the spatial coherence sufficient – which is the case for laser light).
